# HTML Redirect subdirectory back to main page

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I've been looking around the internet and haven't found out how, but have found hints that it's possible to redirect a subdirectory back to the root URL. I'm using logical URLs by way of the .htaccess RewriteRule to mask php files(example being http://my.domain.tld/search/foo/ instead of http://my.domain.tld/search.php?query=foo).

What I want is to have all of my php files in a subdirectory that can't be accessed, such as my.domain.tld/php/searches/search.php, and have any urls that go to /php/ on my server it automatically redirects back to my.domain.tld instead.

Any help pointing me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add .htaccess file into your php directory with the content

```
deny from all
```